# Was Adama's old Viper recovered?

Tags: battlestar-galactica

In the pilot miniseries of the re-imagined Battlestar Galactica, Apollo was flying Adama's old Viper from the first Cylon war. This Viper was damaged when Apollo saved Colonial One from a Cylon missile attack. Was this Viper recovered by Colonial One and later put back in service on the Galactica?

Comment: im pretty sure he crash lands it onto colonial one, and they then repair it and he continues using it for most of the show. as all of the newer vipers wont work until their retrofitted.

Comment: @Himarm is correct and should actually make that the answer. Adama's viper actually continues to be seen right until the end of the series.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Viper that Lee piloted landed on Colonial One after the missile defense. This wasn't shown on-screen; the action cut straight to the cargo hold:

> [image: Viper with Lee]
>
> Lee with Viper in background

Also, the same Viper is seen in the finale, piloted by Bill himself, and you can faintly see "Husker" on the body, which is his callsign.

[image: Husker Viper]

Was this the same Viper all along or just a new one with "Husker" painted on? [According to BSG Wiki](http://en.battlestarwiki.org/wiki/Viper_7242) it's the same one, known as "Viper 7242" although the letters in its serial number are sometimes inconsistent.

So yes, the Viper lasted the entire series.

Comment: While I think that it is reasonable to assume that this Viper was used the whole trip I would not go so far to call it a proof. After all they could simply re-label another Viper. Given that this is the final flight of Galactica they would most certainly do the old man this honour.

Comment: In terms of facts, @Ghanima, you are absolutely correct. But looking at the "spirit" of the show, it seems devastatingly unlikely that they would have bothered doing so at that stage of the game (do you remember what a big deal building the "Blackbird" was?). I think that, for all _practical_ intents and purposes, we can call this a done deal.

Comment: Building the *Blackbird* vs re-labeling an existing Viper? I wouldn't call the latter a big deal (and something they would most certainly do for the Admiral). Sadly enough they should have been acustomed to paint new callsigns to existing Vipers (think of the accident where they lost a bunch of pilots and half the flight deck?)